# My variable can't initialize in for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi guys i have a **For loop** like this

```
 NumberOfSentencesInAbstract=str2double(NumberOfSentencesInAbstract);
 for t = 2:NumberOfSentencesInAbstract
        %move each IWD one step further
        for i = 1:NumIWDs
            k = IWD{i}.tour(t-1);
end 
end
```

The t variable  in the first for can't start and i got this error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

In the workspace the t variable  is something like this :

```
   t=NAN
```

Why ?

Comment: What is the value of `NumberOfSentencesInAbstract` and `NumIWDs`?

Comment: NumberOfSentencesInAbstract =11,and NumIWDs=18

Comment: It is probably not 11 in this case.  If `t` shows up as NaN in the workspace, then `NumberOfSentencesInAbstract` is probably also NaN.  Have MATLAB print those two variables before the loop starts.

Comment: @EA: I am unable to reproduce the problem. Please provide code which allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Peter yes you are right NumberOfSentencesInAbstract  is NAN

Comment: I get the NumberOfSentencesInAbstract correctly .but i convert this using this code :NumberOfSentencesInAbstract=str2double(NumberOfSentencesInAbstract);after this code the value is NAN

Comment: Probably because t not is a number. Why? No idea, I want to go to the moon, where do I live?

Comment: is NumberOfSentencesInAbstract a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line my value goes to be NAN .after removing this line every thing is ok .

```
%NumberOfSentencesInAbstract=str2double(NumberOfSentencesInAbstract);
```

Comment: This is not an answer, since it does not explain why the problem is solved and since this part of the code is not in the question. However I have a clue to why the problem occurs. If `NumberOfSentencesInAbstract` is of a different class than double, then str2double will of course give nan. However, consider removing this answer and also the question.

Comment: thank you .I added this part of code to my question.